# How to convert a string date in european format to a valid mysql date format?

Tags: mysql, date-formatting, str-to-date

I am trying to insert 2 dates through a form in my database, date format in the form is a string like this 01/01/2020 and the field in the database is DATE so I understand it will take YYYY/MM/DD right?

I have trid this query :

```
INSERT INTO property_tenant (id_user, id_property, check_in, check_out) 
VALUES(1375965, 119, STR_TO_DATE("01/01/2020", '%d/%m/%y'), 
                     STR_TO_DATE("01/01/2021", '%d/%m/%y'));
```

I have also tried this :

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE("01/01/2021", '%d/%m/%y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

but I keep getting this error:

> code: '**ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE**',   errno: **1292**,   sqlMessage:
>   "*Truncated incorrect date value: '01/01/2020'*"

Comment: Date's the database ***should*** be stored as YYYYMMDD (`DATE`, `DATETIME` etc.) date format, which is neither US or European style but "Database Style"!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can directly use <kbd>[`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/)</kbd> function as

`STR_TO_DATE('1,1,2021','%d,%m,%Y')`

which already yields a date result. Indeed a date column doesn't have a format within a table. `fmt` part( `'%d,%m,%Y'` ) is just needed to express pieces of the literal conforming with the time portions(`day`,`month`,`Year`) to be ordered correctly.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=38c911d83ff3d0e7c9bad14fa3d8682e)</kbd>

Comment: if the dates entered in the form come separates by / should not I set it like this? ```STR_TO_DATE('1/1/2021','%d/%m/%Y')```

Comment: dunno why it is not working I have updated the query above as it is now but I  get this output:                                                           ```                                                                                                                  INSERT INTO property_tenant (id_user, id_property, check_in, check_out) VALUES (1375965, 119, STR_TO_DATE("01/01/2020", '%d/%m/%y'), STR_TO_DATE("01/01/2021", '%d/%m/%y')) Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect date value: '01/01/2020' 0.000 sec
 ```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=92c618ef7a3eb6a23f612d8145c6cc1b) with capital Y @jesusfernandez

Comment: I must be dumb but it looks exactly the same to what I am doing... I have trid with dd/mm/yyyy in the format also D/M/Y  and all different combinations I do not see where is the mistake...

Comment: :) pay attention to the capital `Y`(consider the demo) @jesusfernandez

Comment: OMG  I thought if I set Y all the other fileds such as day and month shuld be capitals as well, OK sorted now!!! thanks a lot